# Should I normalize values not bigger than 1

Tags: image-processing, classification

I have a question regarding a normalization of values especially in the case of image processing features classification. What if have a series of values that will never be bigger than 1.

A = 0.004 0.032 0.017

Do I still need to normalize it into [0,1] range? The thing is that the A variable will may also contain 0 at some point of the values construction and will never have 1 as its maximum value.

I have another variable like

B = 123.4 5.52 3.44

The B will be normalized.

Comment: I think we are missing some context here.